# Other names for $E_{p+1}$ $\pmod{p}$?

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves, modular-forms

If I want to know properties of $E_{p+1}$ modulo $p$, do you know a name for this modular form, so that it is easier to search via the internet?

So far, what I know is that $E_{p-1}$ is the Hasse invariant, which is connected to supersingular elliptic curves, and that $E_{p+1}$ is connected to $E_{p-1}$ via the Serre-Ramanujan differential operator $\partial$, where we have the identities
\begin{align*}
\partial E_{p-1} &= E_{p+1}\\
\partial E_{p+1} &= -E_4 E_{p-1}
\end{align*}
when working modulo $p$ (and these identities are used to show things like, if $A\in\mathbb{F}_{p}[X,Y]$ is the polynomial such that $A(E_4,E_6)=E_{p-1}$ and $B$ is likewise for $\mathbb{F}_{p}[X,Y]$, then $A$ has no repeated factors and is relatively prime to $B$). However, for a nonexpert like me, it took some digging around until I finally realized $E_{p-1}$ is also the Hasse invariant (and so you could use tools from elliptic curves as well). Is there also a different name for $E_{p+1}$ $\pmod{p}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the only name I know for this besides $E_{p+1}$ is "$B$", which is not
so useful for googling.  Serre's article on modular forms mod $p$ is a standard reference for this sort of thing, by the way.

Comment: Looking back, I think the main thing I needed to know is that multiplying by E_{p+1} increases the filtration by p+1, which I later found in here http://arxiv.org/abs/1301.3087. Also, I'm pretty sure that the w(f^a)=aw(f), where w is the filtration, but do you know if there's a reference I can cite, as it isn't obvious to me from Serre's viewpoint? (something to do with zeros of $E_{p-1}$ being simple, so you aren't going to be able to divide by $E_{p-1}$ more times by taking powers of $f$)

Comment: Sorry, I think I just realized the last comment is essentially it, as if $f^a=E_{p-1}g$, we can evaluate both sides on the zeros of $E_{p-1}$ (supersingular curves), and then I guess we would want to know that if $f$ evaluates to 0 on all the zeros of $E_{p-1}$, then $f$ is divisible by $E_{p-1}$.

Comment: @Dtseng: Dear Dtseng, Yes, since $E_{p-1}$ has simple zeroes, if it divides $f^a$, it already divides $f$.  Regards,

Comment: @Dtseng: P.S. I don't know if it will suit you, since it's phrased in more geometric terms, but the first few sections of Gross's "Tameness criterion ..." paper have a nice summary of mod $p$ modular forms in more geometric terms than Serre (as sections of line bundles on modular curves and so on), which I found helpful when learning the theory of mod $p$ modular forms, and which I continue to find helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I am really not that deep in this but my prime obsessive intuition says that what you are looking for is about the so called "Kummer Congruences of Bernoulli Numbers versus Eisenstein series". Have a look here or just google on this term for various other sources.

http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022314X02928027